# How to exit from UITabBarController to UINavigationController on button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a MainMenu which navigates me to a TabBarController with 4 views (4 Tabs) in it.

Now I've a button in the 4th view of the TabBarController which OnClick should take me to the MainMenu.

Problem is when I pushViewController (MainMenu) I'm not able to dismiss the TabBarController and also NavigationBar is not visible on the MainMenu!!

Can someone please suggest me how to solve this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: MainMenu which navigates me to a TabBarController??
what are using for this? show some code for it

Comment: It's a 'Single View Application' with MainMenuViewController in which I'm having several buttons. On click of one of those buttons takes me to a TabBarController which is having 4 views. In the final view I'm having a button which on click should take me back to the MainMenuViewController. But the problem is when I does [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES]; I'm still not exiting from TabBarController but MainViewController in coming inside the TabBarController!!

Comment: how you navigate to `TabBarController` ? using presentViewController?

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarControllerViewController animated:YES]; This is how I'm navigating from MainMenuViewController to the TabBarControllerViewController page where I'm having 4 views in an array with TabBarController

Comment: have you try `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` this on 4 view's button,

Comment: Yes I've tried it but it's not responding!! [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES]; is atleast taking me to MainMenuViewController but within the TabBarController with out Navigation Bar. The 4 tabs in tabControllerViewController are also ViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use this :

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES];
```

Try using this:

```
 [self.navigationController popViewController Animated:YES];
```

Take the reference of your same MainMenu and then push to that view controller

Comment: It's throwing exception when I tried it. [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainMenuViewController animated:YES]; is atleast taking me to MainMenuViewController but within the TabBarController with out Navigation Bar. The 4 tabs in tabControllerViewController are also 4 different ViewControllers in an array.

Comment: your tabbarcontroller should be in a navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```

UITabBarController is a container controller and you're adding viewControllers into it like so:

NavController
      ||
TabBarController
      ||
DisplayingViewController

since displayingViewController doesn't have a navigationController associated with it but the TabBarController does, you need to call for its parentViewController.